# NestJS importing ESM and having public property type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, langchain

I am using langchain library in NestJS.  Langchain is ESM so following docs I have added a dynamic import like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class LangchainService {
  public openAI: any;

  constructor() {
    this.loadOpenAI();
  }

  private async loadOpenAI() {
    const { OpenAI } = await import('langchain');
    this.openAI = new OpenAI(/* your config here */);
  }

}
```

But I don't want `openAI` property to be `any`.  How do I give it a type?

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: related with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265420